# How to clean up Docker for Mac containers

Tags: macos, disk-space, docker

I'm using [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/) Version 1.12.0-beta21 (build: 11019) on OS X 10.11.6. The container folder in `$HOME/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker` contains 3.1 GB of space. `docker images -a` however only shows one image which is 330 MB.

How can I clean up the container folder, so that it only contains the images I'm able to use?

## Update

There is an open issue regarding this problem: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/371

Answer (score 24):

try:

```
docker system prune -a
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/

> Remove all unused containers, networks, images (both dangling and
>   unreferenced), and optionally, volumes.

Comment: Does not work. Gives `Total reclaimed space: 0B` Still with `du -hs ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker` I get `16G`

Comment: This works for me.

Answer (score 11):

Spotify have a useful docker image called [docker-gc](https://github.com/spotify/docker-gc) which will clean up unused images.

As per the Github page for it, you can run it as a container itself:

`docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /etc:/etc spotify/docker-gc`

I have that aliased to `docker-gc` which I run periodically to clean things up.

Comment: I'm on OS X and not on linux.

Comment: @ohcibi As am I.

Comment: Okay I misunderstood you before. However I tried that and it even deleted some images and containers but the space ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker consumes is the same.

Comment: Okay I found that: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/371

Comment: Do you know what's the difference between this garbage collector and `docker system prune -a`?

Comment: @Manu No, I don't. `docker system prune` didn't exist when I wrote this answer. It was introduced [5 months later](https://blog.docker.com/2017/01/whats-new-in-docker-1-13/). Also I don't use the `docker-gc` command any more. Looking at the repo though, it looks like the main difference is that you have more control over what gets pruned.

Answer (score 11):

Check the size with this command below:

```
du -h -d 1  ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker
```

You can easily clean up running:

```
docker system prune -a
```

Or restarting the default settings on top bar to clean.

[image]

Or create a script like this link to don't lose the images.

https://blog.mrtrustor.net/post/clean-docker-for-mac/