# Is it safe to remove .docker folder? What is it actually?

Tags: finder, catalina, storage

I'm on a mission to free up HD space and I used [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/) to help find folders & files which are taking up the most space. All is good and well until I saw this particular folder which I am completely unfamiliar with: `.docker`. It's taking up 117.8GB and i want to know whether i can delete it? Is it safe? Is it backed up in time machine backups?

Google just brings up some app framework; and so I'm not sure how essential it is.

Would love your thoughts here.

Comment: Did you install or do you use Docker? What's in the folder? Where is it located? Did you check Time Machine preferences to see whether it's in the exclusion list?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/248814/how-to-clean-up-docker-for-mac-containers

Comment: As far as I know, I didn't install it.  Well, not knowingly. and it's not in the TM exclusion list either. :/